# UIActivityIndicator Not Showing After WebService Has Been Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

In my application, I need to show a `UIActivityIndicator` while waiting for response from web service. I am using the following code:

```
  UIView *loadView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
                loadView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];

                //UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
                //[second.loadingView addSubview:activityView];
                //activityView.center = second.loadingView.center;

                //[second.view addSubview:second.loadingView];


                UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                [loadView addSubview:activity];

                activity.center = loadView.center;
                [self.view addSubview:loadView];
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loadView];
                activity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
                [activity setHidden:NO];

                [activity startAnimating];
    // calling My web service            
                [self callRegisterWebService:self.userFname lastName:self.userLName email:self.userEmail];

                [activity stopAnimating];
                [loadView setHidden:YES];
```

However, the indicator does not show up..!! What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Is the `callRegisterWebService` method synchronous ? If it's not, it will return immediately and the `[activity stopAnimating]` will be called immediately.

Comment: Look at this other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320707/uiactivityindicatorview-not-rendering?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably waiting for the http response on the main thread. Try to implement the registration with `dispatch_async` function like this:

```
[activity startAnimating];
// calling My web service
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self callRegisterWebService:self.userFname lastName:self.userLName email:self.userEmail];
    [activity stopAnimating];
});
```